# dtrace a user process which will run in future

Tags: dtrace

There is a user process-1 which can 'exec' a second process-2. Can I dtrace this second process-2 when I don't know when it might be created. I can't use both '-p' and '-c' option with dtrace script without knowing the pid and don't want to exec the process manually.

Using the PID provider I get a namespace error (function not belonging to the process 1). I tried "::functio_name:entry /execname == "process-2"/ {}, but this doesn't compile for userspace programs.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this [post](https://blogs.oracle.com/chrisg/entry/follow_fork_for_dtrace_pid) can help you. You need `2` DTrace scripts:

(1) The first script is used to track when the `process-2` is started. Once it begins to run, start another script to trace `process-2`:

```
# cat followfork.d
proc:::start
/ppid == $target/
{
    stop();
    printf("fork %d\\n", pid);
   system("dtrace -qs child.d -p %d", pid);
}
```

(2) The second script traces focused functions:

```
# cat child.d
pid$target::function_name:entry
{
    ......
}
```

You can also refer related discussions on `DTrace` mailing list:
[How to trace libc module of both parent andchild processes?](http://www.listbox.com/member/archive/184261/2014/10/sort/time_rev/page/1/entry/9:23/20141024035117:86AB9964-5B52-11E4-B31A-8D141F3E1E09/)
[When a process is stopped by stop() action, when and how does the process is restarted?](http://www.listbox.com/member/archive/184261/2014/10/sort/time_rev/page/1/entry/7:23/20141028001929:9A1DB112-5E59-11E4-B986-B8163FF239E9/)

BTW, you can also refer **Sergey Klyaus's** [Dynamic Tracing with DTrace & SystemTap](http://myaut.github.io/dtrace-stap-book/kernel/proc.html) to check which probes should be used in process creation:
[image]